# Azure API App authentication

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps

So I have an Azure API-App with protection working.

I want to use `microsoftaccount` and `google` as tokenname for `GetRawTokenAsync`.

How can I know before which token name to use? Can I obtain that from the current user info?

So something like:

```
var runtime = Runtime.FromAppSettings(Request);
var user = runtime.CurrentUser;         

if (user == "google account") { // google account    
   var token = await user.GetRawTokenAsync("google");    
}    
else if (user == "microsoft account") { // microsoftaccount    
   var token = await user.GetRawTokenAsync("microsoftaccount");    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.Result` to the `GetRawTokenAsync` call

> var runtime = Runtime.FromAppSettings(Request);
>
> var user = runtime.CurrentUser;
>
> TokenResult token = await  user.GetRawTokenAsync("google").Result;
>
> var name = (string)token.Claims["name"];